# Options for breathing underwater

Tags: dnd-5e, adventure-writing, underwater

I'm taking the plunge (pun intended) and having a go at writing my own aquatic based adventure. I intend to use settings of a port, a ship, underwater and a hidden (air and water) cavern.

I've compiled a decent long list of NPCs and Monsters that would work well in these settings, but I'm unsure about the underwater part of the adventure.

What options are available for me to give my characters the ability to breathe underwater?

The only things I can think of at the moment are:

- some kind of magic
- some kind of invention (a primitive aqualung)

Does anyone know of any other options that I may be missing?

Comment: Are you looking for a list of spells and magic items that give the ability to brethe underwater, or a list of ideas that aren't either some kind of magic or some kind of invention?

Comment: @Miniman Either or both would be good. Although I also want to be sure I haven't missed anything else.

Comment: Questions asking for lists of things don't really work at RPG.se. As a rule they result in a continuous trickle of “oh, and one more…” posts and endless maintenance of existing posts, which eventually stop being maintained and then become incomplete/wrong—the worst of both worlds. What would probably be necessary for this to work as an SE-style Q&A is to work on your adventure and then when you have a **specific situation** that you are having difficulty solving, ask about that directly. Answering specific questions with specific answers is the strength and mission of RPG.se.

Comment: “List of all game features giving water breathing” seems like it should work as a bounded list question. The criteria are totally objective, and it shouldn’t be a super long list. Voting to reopen.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov Agreed that a bounded list is a viable question - but shouldn't the question itself be edited to specifically ask for that before it is reopened?  OP hasn't been seen for more than a year...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've basically covered all the bases with "some kind of magic" (ie, all magic) and "some kind of invention" (ie, all technology).

Here's a more fleshed out list for magic (thanks to keithcurtis for providing the latter half of this list):

1. A *potion of water breathing*, or a scroll or spell
2. A *polymorph* spell or scroll -- turn into sea creatures
3. A Druid's Wild Shape, if you have a Druid in the party
4. A *control water* spell or scroll -- create air bubbles for you to breathe
5. Cloak of the manta ray
6. Cap of water breathing
7. Necklace of adaptation

Here's one for technology

1. An artificial aqualung, as you said
2. A series of ports/depots where the aqualungs can be refilled, if this path has been taken by other air breathers before
3. A comically long snorkel
4. A primitive submarine (that will most likely kill everybody inside)

Comment: Haha, 3 and 4 made me laugh. I don't think I'd use them for my PCs, but they may be good for an element of humour with the right NPC. I really like 2 because it would fit in with some of my more nefarious NPCs taking up camp in an underwater cavern system (that does have air) as  a way of getting in and out. It would also require some investigation on the part of my PCs. I suppose I should also give some magical options in case they don't go for the tech route.

Comment: Comically long snorkels would suffocate you, due to your lung capacity probably not being sufficient to push your carbon dioxide _out_ of the snorkel far enough to exhaust it, nor draw fresh air _in_ far enough to ever breathe it.

Comment: But they would provide for a well deserved death. Anyone who thinks they could actually use one is a waste of air, in any case.

Comment: @doppelgreener As you might imagine, the "comically" part of the sentence meant to imply it was a funny suggestion... :)

Comment: @timstermatic It won't necessarily, actually. Here's the trick: 1- breathe *from* your snorkel. 2- remove mouth from snorkel, cover snorkel hole. 3- breathe out into the water. 4- repeat. Alternatively, replace steps 2&3 with breathe out from your nose.

Comment: @timstermatic I stand corrected. I only thought about doppelgreener's argument and based my reply from that, but then I Googled it and found out it's the water pressure around your body that will keep you from inhaling (essentially, you can't puff your lungs out enough to breathe underwater unless through a pressurized tank).

Comment: I'll be slipping the comically long snorkel in for sure. I did like option 2 under tech, though. Also, I'm trying to get my head around the logistics of a submarine.

Comment: You could replace tech Nº4 with an *apparatus of Kwalish*. It can hold 2 medium-size or smaller creatures.

Comment: There's a few magic items missing, cloak of the manta ray, cap of water breathing and necklace of adaptation will all allow breathing underwater.

Comment: Re: snorkel. Not only does water pressure keep you from breathing in, it doesn't take a depth of more than a few feet. I remember having the brilliant idea of using a garden hose as a snorkel in my parents swimming pool. Hint: it doesn't work. Still, it's funny.

Answer (score 1):

Some past editions had Sea Elves who could breath underwater. You could do an aquatic races only game. Just an option.

Comment: the *Sword Coast Adventurer's Guide* has an aquatic elf, I believe. (I don't own it or I'd edit in a mention.) If true, this canonical 5e course would certainly be good to mention.